# Delay loading of a hidden element until you change their properties in javascript to visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, web

I have an element say, an image and other texts inside a div. Initially, this div has a property of `visibility: hidden;` or `display: none;`

How do I prevent the browser to load the contents of this div until I change the property to `visible` or `display: block;`

Comment: What do you mean "load the content"? Browsers will read the elements in HTML DOM regardless of their CSS styling/visibility. You can simply remove them from the DOM and insert dynamically through JavaScript/AJAX

Comment: You can put it on a separate file then load it using Ajax

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to take look at AJAX

Comment: Isn't it better if the browser loads the image *before* you make it visible? That way there isn't a moment (however brief) when the user sees a partially loaded image.

Comment: @nnnnnn suppose the OP's site might have hundreds of images that are in some sort of pagination system, loading them up might not be the best practice, especially for SEO.

Comment: @Aziz my thoughts exactly

Answer (score 0):

you can use a script-block to insert markup that doesn't get parsed.

https://jsfiddle.net/dhj3cshb/

and on show replace it with the real markup

```
function show(node){
    var $node = $(node);
    $node.not('script').css('display', '');
    $node.filter('script').replaceWith(function(){
        return '<div id="'+this.id+'" class="'+this.className+'">'+this.innerHTML+'</div>';
    });
}

function hide(node){
    $(node).css('display', 'none');
}
```

then just toggle the display-status

**Edit:**

if it is just about the lazy loading of images I write the img-src into a data-attribute and have a function that pushes that to the src-property

```
<img data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
```

and js

```
function loadSrcNow(node){
    $(node).filter('img[data-src]').each(function(){
        this.src = this.dataset.src;
        this.removeAttribute('data-src');
    });
}
```